# Unknown class MHRotaryKnob in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, uicontrol

I hav a custom class which is a subclass of UIControl.

Unfortunately i am not able to compile the code due to following error:

`Unknown class MHRotaryKnob in Interface Builder file.`

- I have tried to add the `MHRotaryKnob.m` in `Build Phases -> Compile Sources` i just got a bunch of errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MHRotaryKnob.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MHRotaryKnob.o   "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn", referenced from:
>         -[MHRotaryKnob valueDidChangeFrom:to:animated:] in MHRotaryKnob.o   "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut", referenced from:
>         -[MHRotaryKnob valueDidChangeFrom:to:animated:] in MHRotaryKnob.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

[image]

[image]

- I have tried to clean and rebuild
- I have sweeped content off my simulator

I assume from searching on this particular error its due to the missing sourcefile in my build phase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing framework (QuartzCore) was added, and the problem was solved.